# What is the dimension of the null space of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

If $A$ is a $7\times5$ matrix with $\operatorname{Rank}(A) = 2$, what is the dimension of the null space of $A$? Justify your answer.

Not really sure of the relationship between these things, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Rank-Nullity theorem, which states

If A is m x n matrix then,

Rk(A)+nullity(A)=n

So 2+nullity(A)=5

Nullity(A)=3  ( where nullity is the same as saying dimension of null space)